# Can I shorten | truncate | crop my CSS file with some kind of placeholder?

Tags: css, stylesheet, placeholder

Ok peep's... So I'm creating a **Master CSS** file to use with all my web app's.

---

My first thought was to have every permutation of a `width:` style I'd use, to hand. *ie:*

```
str = '';
ver = 0;
while(1){
    if( ver == 1000 )   break;
    str += '\n.w' + ver + 'x{ width: ' + ver + 'px; }';
    if( ver < 100 ) ver ++;
        else        ver += 100;
}
```

---

Would return the `str` value of:

> .w0x{width:0px;}
>       .w1x{width:1px;}
>       .w2x{width:2px;}
>       ......
>       .w100x{width:100px;}
>       .w200x{width:200px;}
>       .w300x{width:300px;}
>       ......
>       .w1000x{width:1000px;}

Which I would then copy from the browser window into an awaiting file:  `master_snippet.css`.

---

Ok... So there is no problem with the coding, it all works fine.

**The Problem** is the ***conceptual*** finished product.
I'd have to create one of these string for every style I was using *ie:*

> - width
>
>   - min
>   - max
> - height
>
>   - min
>   - max
> - padding
> - margin
> - etc...

Just thinking about the amount of permutations  makes me reach for the asprin bottle ***?!?!?!?!?***
And I'm sure that if my browser was capable, it would do the same when it loaded such a file.

---

### And So, My Question Is...

Is there some kind of ***placeholder*** I can use to save on the written permutations? *ie:*

---

Instead of the having a `.w5x` & `.w10x` instantiated like this:

```
.w5x{width:5px;}
.w10x{width:10px;}

<hr class="w5x">
<hr class="w10x">
```

---

All I'd have to do is instantiate the style **once** in the css document with a ***placeholder***, of let's say **?** for now.

Then when I instantiate the two `<hr>` tags, as above & below, the ***placeholder*** does it's thing and a valid style is appended to the element being styled, which in this case is the `<hr>`'s. *ie:*

```
.w?x{width:?px;}

<hr class="w5x">
<hr class="w10x">
```

---

Comment: Do it properly: [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)

Comment: You can have a look at less css, specially the loops section. Maybe it can be helpful, but i'm not sure as i made just a tiny project using less:
Chek out this example: http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/noDmy

Comment: Or... if you want to go the hard way, you can write a service to parse your stylesheet replacing values (placeholders). [Serving Dynamic Content with HTTP Handlers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx)

Comment: Seems kinda idiotic to produce “versions” from 1px to 1000px for each and every single one of those CSS properties … if you want to pervert the sense behind CSS like this, you’d probably be better off if you just used inline styles in the first place. (Then at least you would not have thousands of classes, most of which will presumably never be used within the actual project.)

Comment: @CBroe: just lookin for a way it improve my coding dude! Chill? Maybe u post a link like MelanciaUK, you know something helpful instead of a simple criticism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cheers dudes, less/sass it is...